# How to add current datetime in POST API request?

Tags: api, postman

I want the start and end date to be in current datetime. I don't know whether it is possible. I need that because I want to trigger the data everyday using my pipeline.

[image: Please see the image here]

Comment: Do you mean that you want it to be filled with today's date automatically? Also the dates in your image only go from 12am to 11:59am (not 11:59pm), is this intentional?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Is it possible?

Comment: What tool are you using to make the request?

Comment: I'm using Postman. and i need to write it in http request body.

Comment: Btw, i need the start time with 12am and end at 11.59pm(not am, that one is a mistake)

Comment: Your question mentions that you want the current datetime but you just clarified that with your most recent comment. You want the 'start' field to be filled with the current date and 00:00:00 (not the current date time), and the 'end' field to be filled with the current date and 23:59:59. If that's true, I suggest editing your question a bit :) Also I'm not clear if you are intending to run Postman on a schedule, if so, perhaps Postman monitors will help. However, I'm not sure if there is a scripting language (or macros) you can use which integrates with Postman monitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove `"start"` and `"end"` from the body of the request and then using Postman's *Pre-request Script* section (next to *Body*), add the following lines:

```js
// Gets current UTC time in the format "yyyy-MM-dd"
const UTCDate = (new Date()).toISOString().split("T")[0];

// Removes manually set values for "start" and "end", if present
pm.request.body.urlencoded.remove(param => param.key === "start" || param.key === "end");
// Adds a parameter "start" set to UTC midnight
pm.request.body.urlencoded.add({ key: "start", value: `${UTCDate}T00:00:00.000Z` });
// Adds a parameter "end" set to just before UTC midnight of the next day
pm.request.body.urlencoded.add({ key: "end", value: `${UTCDate}T23:59:59.999Z` });
```

Answer (score 9):

You can create an environment variable in the pre-request-script of the request and then use that variable in the body

```
var now = new Date();
var timestamp = now.toISOString(); //or whatever format you want.
pm.environment.set("timestamp", timestamp);
```

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, this is by far the best answer.  It can then be used in a request body or headers, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `moment` to make this easier for you. Add this to the `pre-request script`:

```js
let moment = require('moment');

pm.variables.set('startOfDay', moment().utc().startOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
pm.variables.set('endOfDay', moment().utc().endOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
```

The use the `{{startOfDay}}` and `{{endOfDay}}` variables where you need them.

[image: Postman Request]